# Create button not enabled even though there is no validation error when creating sql pool in Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I created a `synapse analytics` workspace. I then tried to create an `sql pool` but the `create` button isn't enabled when I try to create the pool. There is not error message either. I am following the steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-create-sql-pool-portal

[image]

Based on answers below, I gave myself `contributor` access but I still can't create `sql pool`

[image]

Comment: Do you have Azure Contributor role assigned at the Azure Synapse workspace level? If yes, Can you try to log into your Azure Portal in Private tab of your Browser and try creating the dedicated SQL pool as some times cache can be an issue here?

Comment: My role is `Service Administrator
Has full access to all resources in the subscription`

Comment: strangely enough, I could create the pool from synapse studio but not via the azure portal! I didn't even have to create roles.

Answer (score 1):

I created one Synapse Workspace and assigned a User with reader role on the Synapse Workspace and tried creating the Dedicated SQL pool the Create button was disabled like below:-

[image]

When I tried creating Dedicated SQL pool, Create button was not working and got greyed out for me like below:-

[image]

I assigned Contributor role to the same Synapse-User at the Synapse Analytics workspace level like below:-

[image]

Assigned Synapse Administrator role to the user by visiting Synapse Studio like below:-

[image]

You can also assign Synapse Contributor role to the User for Least privileged.

I also assigned Blob Data Contributor role assigned to the Storage account like below:-

[image]

You can also assign the same user access at the resource group level in which Synapse Workspace is deployed so the user inherits the access at the synapse workspace level:-

[image]

Role:-

[image]

Now, I tried creating the Dedicated SQL pool with the same user like below and the Dedicated pool got created successfully:-

[image]

[image]

I also tried to create the Dedicated pool from synapse studio and it got created like below:-

[image]

[image]

Reference:-

[Access control in Synapse workspace how to - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control)

[Create button for dedicated sql pool is grayed out - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1084258/create-button-for-dedicated-sql-pool-is-grayed-out) By AnnuKumari-MSFT

Comment: strangely enough, I could create the pool from synapse studio but not via the azure portal! I didn't even have to create roles.

Comment: Looks like an transient issue on Azure Portal, You can check Azure status or Azure service health to check if there's any affected resource also, You can raise an Azure Support request from here:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request